# fragment in view pager not working properly

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, android-viewpager, fragment

I implemented view pager in my activity like :

```
class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
        ActionBar.TabListener {

    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private TabsPagerAdapter mAdapter;
    private ActionBar actionBar;
    // Tab titles
    private String[] tabs = { "FIRST", "SECOND", "THIRD" };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_welcome);

        // Initilization
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
        getActionBar().setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);   
        // Adding Tabs
        for (String tab_name : tabs) {
            getActionBar().addTab(getActionBar().newTab().setText(tab_name)
                    .setTabListener(this));
        }
```

but when I swipe between tabs it never call the oncreateview of THIRD fragment but it actually call the oncreateview of THIRD fragment when I swipe to the SECOND fragment (From first to Second) and the oncreate view of second fragment get call along with the first fragment.

I don't understand what's wrong with the flow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with this. when you swipe to new page in `viewpager`, it automatically loads the two neighbor fragments of current visible fragment. why? because of having better `UX`.

Can I prevent it from doing that?

No.

Can I extend it to load more neighbor fragments?

yes, [setOffscreenPageLimit](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setOffscreenPageLimit%28int%29)